# Update MySQL NULL values based on join from another table

Tags: mysql

I have two tables, one Master and one ExtraData. Both tables share columns `FirstName, LastName, Gender and A_Id`.

The query I am working on should compare the two tables and `UPDATE` any NULL values for `A_Id` in Master using `A_Id` in Extra.

What is the best way to do this? I could compare `CONCAT(FirstName, LastName, Gender)` but I'm stuck on how to update the column based on a `JOIN`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use many criteria in a join, and then simply set a column in one source table to the value of a column in the other table:

```
UPDATE Master 
JOIN ExtraData 
  ON Master.FirstName = ExtraData.FirstName
  AND Master.LastName = ExtraData.LastName
  AND Master.Gender = ExtraData.Gender
SET Master.A_Id = ExtraData.A_Id 
WHERE Master.A_Id IS NULL
```

Note that the JOIN condition can be made more succinct (because the columns are named the same): `JOIN ExtraData USING (FirstName, LastName, Gender)`

Comment: Ahh interesting, I've never understood USING before. That's far simpler than I expected. Thanks!

Comment: Yeah, `USING` is the only motivation I have for naming primary keys like this: student_id `instead` of `students.id`, since it makes it so easy :-)